# How do I hide an element based on partial HREF?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide some specific adds on my page based on their `href` property(using CSS). I scrolled through some of the answers which tells about hiding an element based on its `href` value. But, the element here is quite dynamic and keeps changing every time I load the page. Is there any way to hide an element/anchor based on its partial `href` value ?

Below is the HTML code that I am trying to hide.

Code:

```
<div id="union-ad" class="union-banner">
<a href="http://someURL?Dynamic_Id's">
</div>
```

This is what i have been trying so far.

```
   <style type="text/css">
   a[href='someURL']{ display: none }
   </style>
```

Comment: is there any posiblity to add some class to this <a> tags which u want to disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a substring selector:

```css
a[href^="http://someURL"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://otherURL.com?hey">You CAN see me.</a>
<a href="http://someURL.com?hey">You can't see me!</a>
```

- [Get more info on substring attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*`. This finds the string partial `someURL` anywhere in the element's `href` attribute.

```
a[href*="someURL"]{ display: none }
```

**Demo:**

```css
a[href*="someURL"]{ 
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="union-ad" class="union-banner">
    <a href="http://someURL?Dynamic_Id's"> my Link </a>
    <a href="http://some?Dynamic_Id's"> other Link </a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/30q2s8xm/)

Comment: The question seems to inquire that the first part of the URL is always known, so using `*=` is risky, as it might as well match any random url by pure chance - whenever possible, I'd prefer `^=`

Comment: @TheThirdMan the question is about partial string href

Answer (score 1):

You have two different choices of [substring selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), which you should select between based on the nature of the URL.

If your URL always starts with the same set of characters, including the protocol specification, then `^=` is the best choice - it will only match elements which href-attribute *begins* with the given set of characters. This will pretty much eliminate the chance of randomly hiding other links because they randomly contain your selector.

```
a[href^='http://someURL'] {
  display: none;
}
```

However if you're entirely unsure about the consistency of the URL and only know a certain part in the middle, use `*=`, which will match elements that *contain* at least one instance of the set of characters given.

```
a[href*='someURL'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there's a [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp) for that.

```
a[href~=someURL] { display: none }
```

Comment: This will only match attributes that contain the word "someURL" surrounded by whitespace characters, so it probably won't be very useful for URLs.